# compare IP address with text file - Power Shell

Tags: string, list, powershell, comparison, text-files

I have a large txt file with hundreds of entries, which looks like this:

```
AUT-NE;server1.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;30-254
AUT-DE;server2.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;30-254
AUT-LI;server3.test.root.local;10.164.22.0;1-254
....
```

So the structure of the txt files is: **location; servername; IP Network Address; IP Range**

And I want to compare an IP-address (=>a string) with the txt file and check which server would be the right one.
For example: A client has the IP address 10.164.22.101, then the correct server would be server3.test.root.local because 10.164.22.101 is in the range of 10.164.22.1 -10.164.22.254.

So my output in this case should be somehting like this: **"Match found: server3"**

How can I do this with Powershell?

I've got

```
$ip = "10.164.22.101"
$sep = $ip.LastIndexOf(".")

$network = $ip.substring(0,$sep) 
$node = $ip.substring($sep+1)
```

So $network is 10.164.22 and $node is 101.

But how can I do the right node comparison and find the matching server?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just trying, but bit more complex and not quickest against a huge list

```
$servers = Get-content C:\PSProject\somefile.txt
$ip = "10.164.22.1"

foreach ($server in $servers) {

$range = $server.split(";")[2] #to get ip address from server variable

$numbertoCheck = $server.Split(";")[3]   # to get the range 0-254
[int]$firstNum = $numbertoCheck.Split("-")[0] # 0
[int]$endNum = $numbertoCheck.Split("-")[1]   # 254



$fromRange = $range.Substring(0, $range.LastIndexOf(".")) # to get 10.164.22 from server variable
$fromIP = $ip.Substring(0, $ip.LastIndexOf("."))          # to get 10.164.22 from ip variable


[int]$iplastOctet = $ip.split(".")[3] # to get last octet from ip variable

if ( ($fromIP -eq $fromRange) -and ([int]$firstNum -le [int]$iplastOctet) -and ([int]$endNum -ge [int]$iplastOctet) ) { # if True

        Write-Host "Match found in $($server.Split(";")[1])"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See: [Performance Considerations/Looking up entries by property in large collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#looking-up-entries-by-property-in-large-collections):

> It's common to need to use a shared property to identify the same record in different collections, like using a name to retrieve an ID from one list and an email from another. Iterating over the first list to find the matching record in the second collection is slow. In particular, the repeated filtering of the second collection has a large overhead.

```
# $List =  Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' .\List.csv
$List = ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' @'
location;servername;IP Network Address;IP Range
AUT-NE;server1.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;30-254
AUT-DE;server2.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;30-254
AUT-LI;server3.test.root.local;10.164.22.0;1-254
'@
```

Instead, create a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable) that uses the concerned subnet as a key and the matching object as the value:

```
$LookupHash = @{}
$List| Foreach-Object {
    $LookupHash[$_.'IP Network Address' -Replace '(?<=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\..*'] = $_
}
```

Looking up keys in a hash table is much faster than filtering a collection by property values. Instead of checking every item in the collection, PowerShell can check if the key is defined and use its value.

```
$LookupHash['10.164.22.101' -Replace '(?<=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\..*'].servername
server3.test.root.local
```

**Update** with regards to the additional question:

> Learnt something new here, but what if two lines with same first 3 octets. for ex:
> `AUT-NE;server1.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;0-50`
> `AUT-DE;server2.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;50-254`

In that case you might refer your dictionary to a list of objects that have the same subnet:

```
$LookupHash = @{}
$List| Foreach-Object {
    $Subnet = $_.'IP Network Address' -Replace '(?<=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\..*'
    if ($LookupHash.ContainsKey($Subnet)) {
        $LookupHash[$Subnet].Add($_)
    }
    else {
        $LookupHash[$Subnet] = [Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$_
    }
}
```

```
$LookupHash['10.164.202.101' -Replace '(?<=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\..*'].servername
server1.test.root.local
server2.test.root.local
```

Comment: Learnt something new here, but what if two lines with same first 3 octets. for ex: ```AUT-NE;server1.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;0-50
AUT-DE;server2.test.root.local;10.164.202.0;51-254 ```

Comment: I have updated the answer with the additional question in your comment