# Extract lines from file A containing values from file B and save extracted lines to file C using Powershell

Tags: powershell, dictionary

I have 2 files where the bigger one contains values like
AAABBBCCCDDD***NNN and smaller one with values like AAABBBCCC
It's necessary to match AAABBBCCC from the smaller file with the same value in the bigger one and then - write line from the bigger file to a new file.
I wrote the script below and it works, but works very slow. I'm thinking about dictionaries, but can't fully understand how it works and can be useable in my case.

```
$bigger_file = 'bigger.txt'
$smaller_file = 'smaller.txt'
$result = 'result.txt'
foreach($line in Get-Content $bigger_file) {
    $shorten_line = $line.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($line.Length, 25))
    $pattern = '^' + [regex]::escape($shorten_line) + '.*'
    if ((Select-String -Path $smaller_file -Pattern $pattern | select-object -First 1) -ne $null) {
    $new_line = $line -replace '"', '\"'
    $final_line = $new_line -replace '', '\u001D'
        '"' + $final_line + '",' | Out-file -Append -FilePath $result
    }
}
```

Hope to get experience with dictionaries and speedup the script as both files contains 100-200k lines.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what the file contents look like exactly? Just a short sample, 5 lines from each

Comment: Just answered a similar(?) question, see: [compare IP address with text file - Power Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76254080/1701026). Aside from @MathiasR.Jessen  comment, what is in `$shorten_line` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is taking X x Y time where X is the size of one file and Y is the time of the second file.  Using a dictionary will make the time Log(X) x Y.  First you would need to create the dictionary in one loop from one file.  Then in second loop read the second file and lookup values in dictionary.  The fastest results will be from making the larger file the dictionary.  Below is code to create and read a dictionary

```
#Create a dictionary
$dict = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]]::new();

#Add a value to a dictionary
$dict.Add("abc","xyz")

#Find a key in the dictionary
$results = $dict["abc"]

#Display results
$results
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it's necessary to create 2 dictionaries and add both files there.

Comment: I takes time to create a dictionary.  When merging to lists you only need to create one dictionary and the enumerate through second list looking up each key in dictionary.  It is more work to create two dictionaries and then merge the two dictionaries.